# testMatch glob pattern unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, jestjs, glob

I'm currently trying to configure my jest.config.js file - more specifically the pattern matching for the tests:

```
 // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: [
    '**/test/*.ts'
  ],
```

This isn't working as expected however. The file structure is as follows:

```
src 
|
 -> jest.config.js

test 
| 
 -> test1.ts
 -> test2.ts
```

Essentially, I just want testMatch to go ../test/*.ts and read run all the files there, but that is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Not working how exactly? any error messages? how do you get it trying read/exectute the files? With as much information you've provided the only definite answer you could possible get is "you are doing something wrong there".

Comment: I've explained that it's not matching the two files within /test. It's matching 0 files.

Comment: Those paths are relative to the Jest root dir: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#rootdir-string. Typically you don't put the config file in src because it's not really source code.